# .net core docker centos HttpRequest error: (Socket Exception) Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core, centos

I have spent a lot of time and tried everything that I could find on Google but could not make it work.

1. I have a working docker container with a .Net Core app 3.1 Blazer.
2. I have hosted this on a Linux server centOS 8. It looks like a clear docker container without Kubernetes, etc...
3. I can open my web site and use it

But I can't send requests from my app, something like the following:

```
var response = await (await httpClient.GetAsync($"requestString}")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

At this part of code i have error:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable
>    ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
>      at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: What is the `requestString` you are using? How do you have your container ports mapped? How do you get to your website? Is that code running in your container or are you using a client to try to reach the container?

Comment: Is this a request you're making from your app hosted in the container to an external resource?

Comment: @stuartd, yes, exactly!

Comment: @Gekctek, im trying send request from my app to resourse. requestString, sorry, i forgot "{", its request string to resource. Im launch my docker image like this: docker run -d -p 80:8008 blablabla:blabla. And it works, but i cant send requests from my app =(

Comment: Could be some networking issues. I like to sanity check if the container can see the outside world. You can get into a running container with `docker exec -it “container-id” /bin/bash` and then do something like `ping google.com` to see if your container can resolve a domain/connect to it

Comment: @Gekctek, you are thinking close, firewall....see my answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Turn off firewalld, then restart docker.

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
sudo systemctl disable firewalld
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a netcore app which could not access a custom hosts entry.

Kudos to @gekctek for pointing me in the right direction, I found that my docker container could access the internet, but that the container could not access a custom entry in my host's /etc/hosts file

To get around this, I added a volume mapping in the docker-compose file so that the container's /etc/hosts entry would match that of the host, and it worked

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After rotating your cluster certificates you may see a persistent error with pods crashlooping with this error.

Scale down to 0 nodes and scale up again to resolve this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27850459)

Comment: Hi @JacobTomlinson, the unedited answer did answer the question (Resource temporarily unavailable was fixed) - the edit by another user has made it substantially less clear

Comment: I've rolled back the edit and made some edits myself to turn this into more of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error with Docker Swarm - tried disabling firewalld as per above but in the end, for my .NET container I had forgotten to add access to the external network so it could hit the internet - it only had access to the internal network. The ultimate firewall..